# Panel Location Sliding Effect in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, timer, panels

what's wrong in my code? my syntax is right, the logic and concept is right.
but when i run the program and pressed the button(that make the panel slides UPWARD) the panel doesn't stop. even though I put a condition inside the timer.

here's the code;

```
Private Sub btn_existing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_existing.Click
        timerPanelSlider3.Start()
        pnl_info1.Enabled = False
        pnl_options.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub timerPanelSlider3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerPanelSlider3.Tick
    yy -= 5
    pnl_existing.Location = New Point(4, yy)
    'pnl_existing.BringToFront()

    If pnl_existing.Location.Y = 225 Then
        timerPanelSlider3.Stop()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well then `pnl_existing.Location.Y` must never = 225. Please debug your work.

Comment: you decrement the location by 5, but only test for when it is precisely 225 for stopping.  what if the decrementing causes it to step over that amount?

Comment: what do you mean @plutonix

Comment: @OneFineDay i already checked if pnl_existing gets 225 and pnl_existing gets the value of 225

Comment: how do i checked it? i put msgbox("225") in the condition inside the timer_tick.

Comment: `If pnl_existing.Location.Y <= 225 Then`

Comment: @theBlueDog i used your code but i changed it into If pnl_existing.Location.Y <= 225 Then and i get the desired output. thank you.

Comment: Don't thank me, @Plutonix already told you what the problem was.

Comment: `MsgBox("225")` will **always** show a message box with the text `225`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get his/her point.

Comment: ...and learn to use breakpoints - MsgBox is a horrible way to debug code

Comment: @bjorn-rogerkringsja so what should i need to improve in making condition like this? in timer??

Comment: sorry @plutonix i'm a newbie in vb.net

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(...)` will send info to the output window; using a breakpoint allows you to see the value of something (such as `yy`) just by holding the mouse over it.

Comment: What was the starting value of `pnl_existing.Location.Y`?

Comment: thank you @plutonix i will make it a hobby to debug a program.

Comment: @OnefineDay the starting value of pnl_existing.location.y is 626 it is located at the bottom of the form and will show upward if i press a button.

Comment: That is not divisible by 5 so it would never land on 225, it would have hit 226 then jump to 221 - so it never hit 225 - see? Use the < operator so when it is lower then 225 it will stop.

Comment: ahh. now the condition for me is clear. thanks for the info. @onefineday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Location.Y` is not hitting 225 you can check if it gets below 225. Or change it's starting position to 625.

```
Private Sub btn_existing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_existing.Click
    timerPanelSlider3.Start()
    pnl_info1.Enabled = False
    pnl_options.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub timerPanelSlider3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerPanelSlider3.Tick
 yy -= 5
 pnl_existing.Location = New Point(4, yy)
'pnl_existing.BringToFront()

 If pnl_existing.Location.Y < 225 Then
    timerPanelSlider3.Stop()
 End If

End Sub
```